# Is this possible: JPA/Hibernate query with list property in DTO method

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hql

In hibernate I want to run this JPQL / HQL query:

```
select new AppointmentDTO(a.id,a.payment)
From Appointment a
WHERE a.hospitalId = :hospitalId
```

AppointmentDTO class

```
@Entity
public class AppointmentDTO {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Integer appointmentId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "paymentId")
    private List<Payment> payment;

    public Integer getAppointmentId() {
        return appointmentId;
    }

    public List<Payment> getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }
    public AppointmentDTO(Integer appointmentId, List<Payment> payment) {
        super();
        this.appointmentId = appointmentId;
        this.payment = payment;
    }
}
```

Appointment class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "<tablename>")
public class Appointment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "paymentId")
    private List<Payment> payment;

//getter and setter
```

when i execute,i get this error like:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.followMyDoctor.DTO.AppointmentDTO]. Expected arguments are: int, java.util.Collection [select new AppointmentDTO(a.id,a.payment) From ........ = :hospitalId]
```

What is the error in select statment, is it possible to get the expected result?
Is it possible to get onetomany in DTO method

Comment: Please elaborate the problem statement.

Comment: @krishnkantjaiswal i need to execute this query using DTO 
select new AppointmentDTO(a.id,a.payment)
From Appointment a
WHERE a.hospitalId = :hospitalId

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I already added   Integer appointmentId, List<Payment> payment

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not set any Hibernate related annotations/mappings in your DTO class, as they are already there in your Entity class.
2. Make sure that `Payment` object is of same class in both the Entity and DTO classes, if they are not same, than that is a mismatch of class.

This is how your DTO should look ideally:

```
public class AppointmentDTO {

    private Integer appointmentId;

    private List<Payment> payment;

    public Integer getAppointmentId() {
        return appointmentId;
    }

    public List<Payment> getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }
    public AppointmentDTO(Integer appointmentId, List<Payment> payment) {
        super();
        this.appointmentId = appointmentId;
        this.payment = payment;
    }
}
```

Also when using non-entity classes in JPQL, mention full package name along with class like below:

```
SELECT new com.your.package.AppointmentDTO(...) FROM ...
```

Comment: yes that ok. Is it correct SQL select query?

Comment: Yes your JPQL seems correct, but as I said just make sure the class of `Payment` in both the entity and DTO classes is same. User defined classes are the issues in most of such cases.

Comment: IF i remove annotation error like "Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: AppointmentDTO, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(payment)]
"

Comment: Which annotation are you talking about? No annotation is required in DTO. Can you paste full stacktrace of this exception.

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.followMyDoctor.DTO.AppointmentDTO]. Expected arguments are: int, java.util.Collection [select new AppointmentDTO(a.id,a.payment) From com.followMyDoctor.models.Appointment  where a.hospitalId = :hospitalId]

Comment: when remove @onetomany mapping in DTO class i got error like "Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: AppointmentDTO, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(payment)]
"

Comment: Remove all the annotations from DTO. Even `@Entity` annotation.

Comment: i removed all annotation in dto then i got error like  " Unable to locate class [AppointmentDTO]
[cause=org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [AppointmentDTO]]
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.DetailedSemanticException: Unable to locate class [AppointmentDTO]"

Comment: Write full package name `new com.your.package.AppointmentDTO(...)` in JPQL.

Comment: yes i tried error "]ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker:57 -  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.test.DTO.AppointmentDTO]. Expected arguments are: int, java.util.Collection. [cause=org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.followMyDoctor.DTO.AppointmentDTO]"

Comment: Are those `Payment` classes in both Entity and DTO same? Because this same type of queries are working in my Code. Once try removing `a.payment` from JPQL and also from constructor and try again.

Comment: i treid..but didn't get :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the constructor syntax only works for passing singular attributes. If you want to do this, you have to "flatten" and group the result set manually with streams or a for each loop.

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Appointment.class)
public interface AppointmentDTO {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getAppointmentId();
    Set<PaymentDto> getPayment();

    @EntityView(Payment.class)
    interface PaymentDto {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getId();
        BigDecimal getAmount();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`AppointmentDTO a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, AppointmentDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<AppointmentDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!